# Manually deleting a java duplicate entry

Tags: android

I am currently trying to fix an **app:tranformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug** error in the gradle build.

I have been attempting to run my app on my phone, but the Studio keeps on outputting the error

> Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

It said that there was a duplicate entry.

I searched it up on Stack, and it reccomended entering the following command on my console: `./gradlew clean`

The command didn't work, so I decided to try and delete it manually. Only problem is, I have no idea how to delete it manually.

The entry is **com/google/firebase/FirebaseNotAvailableException.class**

Any idea on how to find these kinds of classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this class in Android sdk,
the folder that contains your downloaded SDK has various folders and such type of java files are inside that only.

eg- Android\Sdk\extras\android